# Git, delete some files but keep them untracked & ignored when pulling

Tags: git

I'm currently in the process of removing lots of unnecessary files from a project and there are some particular paths that I'd like to keep on `.gitignore` but still present on the different servers, just not tracked.

I need the different servers to do this also when fetching the committed changes (i.e. don't remove the files, keep them locally, untracked and ignored).

For the sake of example, from this directory and intended result:

```
mydir/
├── directory1    # Keep ignored & untracked
├── directory2    # Merge modifications
├── directory3    # Remove completely
├── file1         # Keep ignored & untracked
├── file2         # Merge modifications
└── file3         # Remove completely
```

What would be the difference between deleting `directory1` and `file1` normally, as opposed to the command used to delete `directory3` and `file3` so that this change is persistent across different clients that will fetch the changes in this branch?

**Note** I need this change to be:

1. Persistent across clients (through pull)
2. Applicable on two different branches without losing the ability to merge them.

*Update:* I just found [this write up](http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/untrack-files-in-git-repos-without-deleting-them/) explaining one possible way to do this by creating a bash script that does `git rm --cache`, the problem with this is that when reproducing on different servers with pull, I'm getting those files deleted.

Comment: You could "track" the file you wanted to delete, and .gitignore those you didn't.

Comment: Yeah, but is this replicated on a pull on the other servers?

Comment: @OMGtechy Without actually deleting them, just add them to ```.gitignore``` ? Note that I want to actually delete those from the git cache, since I want that disk space freed up

Comment: @martin Yes, it's replicated on a ```pull``` (or other way such as fetch & merge if it's necessary for my requirements)

Comment: @AlainJacometForte Sorry, my comment was meant for OMGtechy. I understand that you want to have it replicated.